# BOSCH CAN 2.0 with ISO 11898 High Speed CAN

Tags: digital-logic, pic, can, bus

I'd like to use the [PIC18F25K83-E/SS](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18(L)F2526K83-Data-Sheet-DS40001943C.pdf) micro controller with the [TCAN332](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tcan337.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1672351299082&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftcan337) transceiver to implement a CAN node. In the PIC documentation it specifies the BOSCH CAN 2.0 standard while the TCAN322 specifies the ISO 11898 high speed physical layer. Are these two standards compatible? My understanding is that since one is specifying the physical layer and the other is specifying the transfer layer that they should be compatible (assuming all other nodes on the bus use the same setup of course). Is this assumption correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will work just fine together.

As you say, ISO 11898-2 only defines the physical layer, while CAN 2.0 is basically ISO 11898-1, that defines the data link layer.

Take a look at figure 1 in this preview of ISO 11898-1: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:11898:-1:ed-2:v1:en